# Problemas en POO

Tags: java

Tengo un problema que no logro resolver el programa consiste en crear un menú de forma aleatoria almacenados en un arreglo de 10 elementos el programa es el siguiente:

```
public class Ejemplo3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Menu m = new Menu();
    Menu m1 = new Menu();
    m.crearMenu();
    m1.mostrar();


}

}

public class Menu {
String entrada [];
String principal [];
String postre []; 
String bebida []; 
int var1, var2, var3, var4;

public void menu() {
entrada = new String [] {"Codito con queso", "Crema Espinaca",
        "Sopa de Verduras","Crema de Champinon","Sopa de codo",
        "Sopa de letras","Espagueti","Crema de elote",
        "Arroz","Huevo"};
principal = new String [] {"Bistek","Filete","Langosta",
        "Mojarra","Hamburguesa","Lomo","Pechuga Rellena",
        "Consome","Tacos","Caldo de Gallina"};
postre = new String [] {"Fresas con Crema","Ensalada Gaby",
        "Ensalada de manzana","Gelatina","Helado","Pay",
        "Pan de Elote","Pastel","Platanos fritos",
        "Algodon de azucar"};
bebida = new String [] {"Agua simple","Coca Cola","Mirinda",
        "Agua de sabor", "Manzanita","Te","Licuado",
        "Leche","Cafe","Sprite"};
}
public void crearMenu() {
var1 = (int)(Math.random()*2);
var2 = (int)(Math.random()*2);
var3 = (int)(Math.random()*2);
var4 = (int)(Math.random()*2);
}
public void mostrar() {
System.out.println("Entrada: " + entrada[var1]);
System.out.println("Principal: " + principal[var2]);
System.out.println("Postre: " + postre[var3]);
System.out.println("Bebida: " + bebida[var4]);
}
```

Este es el error que me arroja:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The public type Menu must be defined in its own file

```
at Menu.<init>(Ejemplo3.java:15)
at Ejemplo3.main(Ejemplo3.java:5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenes dos errores:

1. El **constructor** estaba declarado como un **método**
   `public void menu()`. EL constructor se declara siempre (aunque existen también 
    privados) asi:
   `public Menu()` y por convención empieza con mayúscula
2. Creaste dos objetos `m` y `m1` pero ejecutaste `m.crearMenu` y pediste mostrar `m1`, 
   o sea que a `m1` no le creaste menú y tampoco pedis mostrar a `m`
3. `Math.random()` da un intervalo de valores chicos, digamos que entre 0,01 y 0,99, y al pasarlo a `int` te lo redondea para bajo, o sea que da siempre **0**, por más que lo multipliques por 2, así que un buen multiplicador sería el **10** ya que matemáticamente nunca va a llegar a 10 por que `0,99 * 10 = 9,99`, si llegara a 10 daría error por que ese índice no existe, tu arreglo va del 0 al 9

```
public class Ejemplo3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      m.crearMenu();
      m.mostrar();
      m1.crearMenu();
      m1.mostrar();
    }
}
class Menu {
String entrada [];
String principal [];
String postre []; 
String bebida []; 
int var1, var2, var3, var4;

    public Menu(){
        entrada = new String [] {"Codito con queso", "Crema Espinaca",
                "Sopa de Verduras","Crema de Champinon","Sopa de codo",
                "Sopa de letras","Espagueti","Crema de elote",
                "Arroz","Huevo"};
        principal = new String [] {"Bistek","Filete","Langosta",
                "Mojarra","Hamburguesa","Lomo","Pechuga Rellena",
                "Consome","Tacos","Caldo de Gallina"};
        postre = new String [] {"Fresas con Crema","Ensalada Gaby",
                "Ensalada de manzana","Gelatina","Helado","Pay",
                "Pan de Elote","Pastel","Platanos fritos",
                "Algodon de azucar"};
        bebida = new String [] {"Agua simple","Coca Cola","Mirinda",
                "Agua de sabor", "Manzanita","Te","Licuado",
                "Leche","Cafe","Sprite"};
        }
        public void crearMenu() {
        var1 = (int)(Math.random()*10);
        var2 = (int)(Math.random()*10);
        var3 = (int)(Math.random()*10);
        var4 = (int)(Math.random()*10);
        }
        public void mostrar() {           
        System.out.println("Entrada: " + entrada[var1]);
        System.out.println("Principal: " + principal[var2]);
        System.out.println("Postre: " + postre[var3]);
        System.out.println("Bebida: " + bebida[var4]);
    }
}
```

Comment: se me olvidó también lo que sugirió @isaac, así que ya saqé el `public` de la clase `Menu`

Answer (score 0):

El error es muy claro, indica que la clase `Menu` debe ir en un archivo independiente y que se llame `"Menu.java"` y la clase `Ejemplo3` debe ir en unarchivo con el nombre `Ejemplo3.java`.

Ahora si se desea dejar en un solo archivo, `java` solo permite una clase publica por archivo `.java` en este caso solo quitando el `public` de la clase `Menu` deberia compilar.

Comment: ah se me olvidó eso

Comment: No olvide marcar como respuesta si le ayudo a solucionar su problema

Comment: parece que ya entregó la tarea escolar